# Is this a good scenario for using git push --force? Am I alright to use it in this scenario?

Tags: git

New to git, apologies if this is a stupid question.

I use git on an iOS project I'm working on, and it's only me pushing to a private repository.

I made some pushes, realized that I wanted to completely forget/delete a commit I made, so I `git reset --hard` to that commit, made some further changes, and made a new commit.

I went to push that to my repository, and of course I got a warning that I was behind. I read around a little bit and I got the feeling that `git push --force` would overwrite the remote repository. I get that this would be terrible to do if it was a public repository or one a team looked at, but as it isn't, it seemed fitting to just overwrite the remote repository.

Was it alright to do that? I can't visibly see any issues.

Answer (score 3):

Your conclusion is correct. You can do it because it's only you with one instance of the repository.

However, if you are working with collaborator or you have multiple clones of the repository (for example at work and at home) it may create additional complications when you'll try to push or pull from the outdated copy.

In general, if you shared your commits publicly and you want to remove a commit, it's better to use [`git revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html).

```
$ git revert <commit>...
```

This reverts the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them. The advantage is that it preserves the history and your co-workers will not encounter any issue pulling or pushing.

However, if you need to remove a commit completely, let's say because you published some super secret recipe, at that point the only way is to `reset` and `push --force`.